# Ruby CSV - Write on same row without overwriting?

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm using

`CSV.open(filename, "w") do |csv|`
to create and write to a csv file in one ruby.rb file and now I need to open it and edit it in a second .rb file. Right now I'm using `CSV.open(filename, "a") do |csv|` but that creates new rows rather than adding the new content to the end of the existing rows.

If I use `CSV.open(filename, "w") do |csv|` the second time it overwrites the first rows.

edit:

```
# Create export CSV
final_export_csv = "filepath_final.csv"

# Create filename for CSV file
imported_csv_filename = "imported_file.csv"

CSV.open(final_export_csv, "w", headers: ["several", "headers"] + [:new_header], write_headers: true) do |final_csv|

  # Read existing CSV file
  CSV.foreach(imported_csv_filename) do |old_csv_row|

    # Read a row, add the new column, write it to the new row
    CSV.open(denominator_csv_filename, "r+") do |new_csv_col|


# gathering some data code

          data = { passed.in }

          # Write data
     
          new_csv_col <<
          [
            passedin[:data]
          ]

          old_csv_row[:new_header] = passedin[:data]
          final_export_csv << old_csv_row

        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You can't easily re-write a text file in-place. You need to read it all in, then write it all back out with any modifications.

Comment: If you simply want to add another column named, say, `"new_col"`, whose elements are given by the array `arr`, you are could use ordinary file methods: `File.open('out', 'w') do |fout|; File.foreach('in', chomp: true).with_index { |line,i| fputs ',' + line + i.zero? ? "new_col" : arr[i-1] }; end`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As tadman comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66607177/ruby-csv-write-on-same-row-without-overwriting#comment117745977_66607177), you can't actually edit a file in place. Well, you *can* but all the lines have to remain the same length. You're not doing that.

Instead, read a row, modify it, and write it to a new CSV. Then replace the old file with the new one. Be careful to avoid slurping the entire CSV into memory, CSV files can get quite large.

```
require 'csv'
require 'tempfile'
require 'fileutils'

csv_file = "test.csv"
# Write the new file to a tempfile to avoid polluting the directory.
temp = Tempfile.new

# Read the header line.
old_csv = CSV.open(csv_file, "r", headers: true, return_headers: true)
old_csv.readline

# Open the new CSV with the existing headers plus a new one.
new_csv = CSV.open(
  temp, "w",
  headers: old_csv.headers + [:new],
  write_headers: true
)

# Read a row, add the new column, write it to the new CSV.
old_csv.each do |row|
  row[:new] = 42
  new_csv << row
end

old_csv.close
new_csv.close

# Replace the old CSV with the new one.
FileUtils.move(temp.path, csv_file)
```

Comment: ```# Open the new CSV with the existing headers plus a new one.
new_csv = CSV.open(
  temp, "w",
  headers: old_csv.headers + [:new],
  write_headers: true
)

# Read a row, add the new column, write it to the new CSV.
old_csv.each do |row|
  row[:new] = 42
  new_csv << row
end```

What are you doing with the [:new] header? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: @TaylorDorsett Adding new content to the end of the row. The column header is "new".

Comment: Is there a way to do this without tempfile and fileutils? 

When I try this I get an error type error about trying to convert to a string.

Comment: @TaylorDorsett Yes, you can use a regular file. But where is the error? Is it `CSV.open(temp, ...)`? Try `temp.path`.

Comment: #<TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer> I get a type error if I try to add new columns that way.

I've also gotten TypeError: no implicit conversion of Array into String

Comment: @TaylorDorsett On what lines? And what version of Ruby?

Comment: Just added to my question the code I'm using now. 2.6.1

Comment: @TaylorDorsett You have three CSV files, not two. You're trying to add rows to `new_csv_col` which is open for reading and not a column. Are you sure `passedin` is a Hash? What is `passed.in` and why is it inside a Hash? `data` is never used. I believe your problems are all in your added code.